# Unable to login to Azure using `azcopy login --tenant-id` with the Tenant ID from an Azure Government account?

Tags: python, azure, shell, azcopy, azure-gov

I am using an Azure Government account that has the base URL of `portal.azure.us`. I am trying to use the `azcopy` executable on my macOS and run the command `./azcopy login --tenant-id=<tenant ID>`. I am 100% sure the tenant ID I am using is correct. However, I get the following error:

```
Failed to perform login command: 
failed to login with tenantID "XXXX", Azure directory endpoint "https://login.microsoftonline.com", autorest/adal/devicetoken: -REDACTED- occurred while handling response from the Device Endpoint: Error HTTP status != 200
```

Is this because I am not logged into the Azure Government account properly? How can I get this command to run?

Comment: Not sure if you can try with an Az login first?  It might pick the token and use it for az copy login

Comment: I have used `az login` with it set to AzureUSGovernment, and I retrieved a tenant ID and an ID. I tried using both to login with `azcopy login`, with no avail on either.

Comment: Ahh yes you're right. So when you do `azcopy login tenantId` you get a device code? What if you do az logout and then azcopy login? Just trying different scenarios to see if we can get a different error

Comment: So when I do `azcopy login --tenant-ID`, I receive the error I got above (this happened even after using `az logout` just now). When I use `azcopy login`, I follow the instructions and enter the code, and get this error: `Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '579a7132-0e58-4d80-b1e1-7a1e2d337859'.`

Answer (score 2):

To login to Azure Government with AzCopy, you will need to specify the --aad-endpoint for Azure Government. Try using:

```
azcopy.exe login --tenant-id <tenantid> --aad-endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.us
```